# How to convert django model to abstract model if it already has related classes

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstract-class, django-migrations

Lets say i have the following base model:

```
class human(models.Model):
   gender = models.BooleanField()
   age = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And two models inheriting it:

```
class superhero(human):
   can_fly = models.BooleanField()

class villain(human):
   fingerprint = models.ImageField()
```

At some time in my development process i realized that i don't actually need the human class directly. I only need it to be a set of template parameters for superhero and villain models. If now i go to human `Meta` class and set `abstract=True` and change my models like so:

```
class human(models.Model):
   gender = models.BooleanField()
   age = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True

class superhero(human):
   can_fly = models.BooleanField()

class villain(human):
   fingerprint = models.ImageField()
```

attempt to make migrations and migrate will raise the following error

> Local field u'gender' in class 'superhero' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'human'

How can i switch to abstract class keeping all my migrations without tinkering the database directly?

Answer (score 8):

### So after reading the docs again I found a solution:

The error was raised because of the way Django saves models to the database. All models that inherit from the base model `human` don't have all `human` fields in their own tables. Instead they have only their own fields and a foreign key that links them to the corresponding lines in `human` table. But when you inherit from abstract class all the fields are saved directly to your model's table. So when I tried to change `human` class to `abstract=True` and inherit it in `superhero` class Django tried to create all fields from `human` table in `superhero` table, which still has a foreign key to existing human entry with fields named exactly the same.

### **warning**

Following this instruction will make the desired result but unfortunately **will destroy all entries** of `human` `superhero` and `villain` models

1. Comment `superhero` and `villain` models so Django deletes them
2. Make migrations and migrate so the `superhero` and `villain` tables are deleted
3. Set `abstract=True` in `human` class
4. Make migrations and migrate again. This will delete `human` table because now it is an abstract class
5. Uncomment `superhero` and `villain` models
6. Make migrations and migrate. This will create `villain` and `superhero` tables with all the fields from `human` class

This is it.

P.S. Why I needed to move to abstract class? Because I wanted to make all my `villains` and `superheroes` unique using `unique_together` parameter that makes some DB level restrictions. To make this possible all `superhero` fields had to be in one table. Now it works.

Comment: You can prevent deleting the data by faking migrations. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but the answer saved me a lot of efforts. I just want to add something.

When making a model class to inherite from an abstract model, Django migrations will remove that model.

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    # some fields to be inherited later from the abstract model
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    # other fields specific to this model
```

Now if you create an abstract model:

```
MyAbstractModel(models.Model):
    # fields to be used by children classes

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and let your model inherit from it:

```
MyModel(MyAbstractModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    # other fields specific to this model
```

If you run makemigrations and migrate on your app Django will remove that model and delete the correspondent DB table.

You can outsmart Django by commenting out the code for that model. Django will remove it with all other consequences. Now you can uncomment the code and run the migrations again and Django will create the DB table again.

However you will likely have your admin, views, forms, etc., to import your model. This means the migrations will throw error, because that class can't be found. You'll have to comment out the code in all files where your model is imported.

Easier would be to skip the commenting out and write the wanted migration manually:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # app_label should be your app
        # and 000x_the_last_migration is the name of the migration
        # it depends on, usually the last one
        ('app_label', '000x_the_last_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # do this for all ForeignKey, ManyToManyField, OneToOneField
        # where model_name is obviously the model name and name is the
        # field name
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='author',
        ),
        # finally delete the model
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='MyModel',
        ),
    ]
```

Now you can run the migration:

```
python manage.py migrate app_label
```

later inherit from the abstract model (see code above, 3rd block) and make new migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_label
```

This should save you commenting out large chunks of code. If you want to save the data in the DB table, then you can use `dumpdata` and `loaddata`.

TLDR

This wasn't a step for step guide and requires experience with Django. In short you have to:

1. Create abstract model
2. Write the migration manually for the model that has to inherit from the abstract model
3. Run the migration (this deletes the DB table with all entries!)
4. Inherit from the abstract model
5. Run makemigrations and migrate